# Google Analytics API Filtering out internal IP Address

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I am trying to use Google Analytics API to filter out an internal IP Address. I can only see solutions/guides on how to do this using Supermetrics/Analytics->Admin->User management->Filters option. I want to do this using the API. I just want to filter an API out, I don't want to view IP Addresses (I know this isn't possible). Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not as simple as you think.

The GA APIs include reporting APIs (v3 and v4, MCF and Real Time) that do not have access to the IP ... and a Management API that can create or edit Filters in your GA Account, which needs to be linked to the View you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone looking how to do this:

You can use the Google Analytics Management API to do this, here is the Filter Update Documentation showing you how to do this.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters/update